# Sample Weights procude contradictory results for binary classification with higher precision for less weighted class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using sample_weights to give class 1 higher weight in the loss function, however, If I do so I find that class 0 is the one given higher precision and the model tends to classify most instances as class 1 (the one I given higher weight). I expected the model to pay more attention at the class 1 and it should be the one having higher precision. To get higher precision on class 1, I have to weight class 0 so the model now classifies most instance as class 0 but keeps class 1 very precise. Is this normal?

Comment: You can take a look there that's brievly well explained https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Comment: I know how to calculate the weights of the classes. My dataset is even balanced but the precision/recall is superior in one class over the other. I want to model to equalize both of them through sample_weights. However, when I give higher weight to one class, the other class performs better. It is paradoxial.